# Symfony custom database authentication

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to get users authenticated from my own custom database, I have been following the instructions in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) but I'm a little stuck because I can't seem to figure out how to change that to follow my own table with it's own fields.

My Current database structure is as follows:

```
Table User:
   first_name (string)
   last_name (string)
   id (int) Key
   user_type (int)
   username  (string)
   password (md5(string))
   email (string)
```

I don't really get how I would implement it so that it would authenticate with username or email.

Comment: Maybe you should also read the Doctrine-documentation. The `@ORM\Column`-Annotation has an argument `name=` where you can specify your own name for a table-column with which you can map your model properties to the corresponding table columns, e.g. `User->firstName` maps to `@ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=50)` etc. If something else is troubling you, please expand your question, especially point out what you tried and expected and actual results. Your current question is very vague!

Comment: Ah that explains it, sorry, completely new to the Annotation concept. I'll change my question when I can be more specific thanks.